# Synonym for "scheduled" or "queued"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe a support ticket status that says "we are aware of this issue, and will look into as soon as we can", as opposed to "we are looking into this right now".

*Scheduled* sounds like we have a time in mind, and we are putting it off until that time for no specific reason.

*Queued* sounds like "this issue is just another in the queue, please wait your turn".

We want to communicate "its important to us, but we cant look into it right now. We will look into it as soon as we are done with whatever else has higher priority".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queued means exactly what you described, but you might want to display something a little more euphemistic like "prioritized" to keep your users feeling important.

Comment: I like the sound of that: "prioritized".

Comment: … except that *prioritized* usually means that your ticket has been given priority over others. Every ticket cannot simultaneously be *prioritized*, any more than you can assign them all "#1". *[Triaged](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38642)* would be more accurate, if a little clinical.

Comment: @choster I don't disagree with you, but that's what the OP asked for. He wants users to feel like they're being given precedence, even when they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

So you want it to sound like something is happening even when it isn't...

Tell them their issue is "being advanced" or "is progressing" in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

*We will rank your issue high on our priority list*.

Comment: When is a synonym a full sentence?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd OP didn't ask for a single word.

Comment: So a synonym could be a book that explains the "opposite"?

Answer (score 0):

"Resolution of your issue is [*pending*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pending)".