# Can "triage an issue" mean "debug an issue"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs, subcontinental-english

In the context of my office environment (a tech giant), I often see folks using the word *triage* as a substitute for debugging an issue. Statements like

> We are still triaging the issue...

is quotidian practice on the part of managers and

> I am triaging this...

from engineers.

As per definition of the word, it means "assigning priority to a task". The very fact that the leads have assigned a task to engineers does imply that it's priority has been gauged and somebody has been set upon to debug it further.

Is this an Indianism or is there some other meaning of the term that is being used here?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm aware of the meaning of the word *triage* in the medical and military context. I also do understand that it's a popular term in bug management. My question, as @Kace36 aptly captures, is whether the word should be applied to the ***entire phase*** of determining the root cause of a bug and debugging it, or should it just refer to the step of assignment of a priority to it (probably with the added step of determining *when* to fix it) and is this habit a quirk of the Indian vernacular?

Comment: Check out the full meaning and background info on *triage* -- it's the first step in/before solving a problem. Good Luck.

Comment: No, it's not an Indianism, it's English, of military origins, if it matters anything.

Comment: Technically triage in your context is just prioritizing bugs. But many people will use it to mean the entire process of bug fixing. Some people are even likely using it incorrectly after picking it up in the wrong context. It really exploded in use out of the Agile movement primarily and has become an important part of the software defect and testing processes.

Comment: @Kace36 See my comments above, too. If that was so, why "still"?

Comment: @Kris I don't follow. What do you mean when you say, "why still"?

Comment: @Kace36 Please see my comments above.

Comment: @Kris Yes, I am. I don't know what you mean by "still". Triage is a french originated word out of military units I don't disagree with you. He wanted to know about it in a tech environment. Triage is a common practice in Agile software environments and refers to the assigning of priority to defects. He is asking why are some using it to refer to the actual bug fix process and if that is normal or just an Indian colloquial use.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage  HTH.

Comment: @Kris Yes, I know. I'm fully aware of the original use of the French originated word "Triage". As I said just before. But he doesn't care anything about that. Are you asking why is it still being used in software practices?

Comment: @Kace36  If you are not from the software field, please see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug#Bug_management

Comment: You are misunderstanding. He is a software developer (well most likely - we know he works at a tech giant - he said so). He wants to know if people saying "triage" just means the prioritization of bugs in an Agile setting or if it means the actual debugging process. And if that is correct usage is it local to India only? That is what is being asked.

Comment: To answer Zoso (I didn't realize the comments would get so crazy) I would refer you to my comment above, my first one. That is the answer.

Comment: I guess I am going to have to formally answer this question b/c this is crazy now. LOL. I didn't expect this to happen. That wiki link is not a great link for what he/she is asking. They really want to know about vernacular and if it's Indian only. From that perspective there is some opinion involved but as a 30yr veteran of the CS field I don't feel at all worried about answering the question for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "triage an issue" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/267701/246019)

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the link. I think I understand what triage means. My question was more on the lines of whether its usage in the software industry aligns with the original meaning/intent. Kace36 has actually captured the purpose of my question most aptly.

Answer (score 5):

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/triage):

> Triage is the process of quickly examining sick or injured people, for example after an accident or a battle, so that those who are in the most serious condition can be treated first.

In the context of bug fixing this typically means examining the bug report in a bid to determine the bug's priority and, by extension, its position in a work queue.

So, once the bug has been examined and prioritised then the triage phase ends. I'd suggest that the parallels with triage in emergency medicine break down if people continue to refer to a bug as being in triage after its priority has been assigned.

The term "bug triage" is not an Indianism (Googling "bug triage" will return enough non Indian results to suggest that it is common idiom in the software realm) but perhaps you are asking whether its use *after* the bug has been prioritised is an Indianism. If so, I'd suggest that's simply a misunderstanding of the term and I'd be surprised if that misunderstanding is specific to India :)

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug#Bug_management

Comment: Guys, listen he is not asking about "triage" in the medical sense. This is a software question. I'm very well versed in it and know exactly what he is talking about. It has nothing to do with the original use of the word "triage".

Comment: The definition of triage was offered as background and to make clear where the boundaries of triage lie. Just like in emergency medicine (where triage ends when a decision is made on the urgency of the patient's condition), bug triage typically ends when a priority has been assigned to the bug. I think this is relevant to the OP's question about whether triage continues after "somebody has been set upon to debug it further".

Comment: @glitch Your edit is much better. And yes it did come from that usage and there is an obvious parallel, you are correct. And, yes, what they want to know is if the usage of the actual bug fixing process (which involves various stages) is part of triage. Basically they are saying why do people around my office keep saying triage to mean bug fix when a triage meeting is meant to prioritize a "sprint" (an agile cylce) for bug fixing. Some people are probably doing it b/c they picked it up out of the wrong context in a meeting (something people do WAY too often these days).

Comment: And, no, that issue is not strictly limited to India, trust me Zoso ;)

Comment: Aligns with my suspicion that, this indeed is a misunderstood term in the software domain...It has somehow become irksome when I hear this used (in the wrong sense of course!)

Comment: Triage _should_ according to its original meaning just be a quick prioritisation process to decide which reports of "bugs" should be looked at first. However, extending this a little to encompass deciding if a reported bug really _is_ a bug (and not misuse, misunderstanding etc.) seems fairly normal, and may involve a non-trivial amount of work (trying to reproduce; adding debugging). Extending it to include _fixing_ the bug (unless the fix "fell out" in the earlier investigation) would, I think be taking it too far.

Answer (score 0):

**Triage** is a military/medical term which, while it had been around for decades, gained currency during the Korean War.

The term refers to dividing the wounded into [three categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage):

1. Those who need immediate help
2. Those who can wait for help
3. (Often conveniently omitted in such discussions) Those who are beyond help

However, as currently used in non-medical scenarios the term is often somewhat questionably used to refer to the simple enrollment and classification of problems (ie, entering them into the "bug list"), without division into "urgent" and "non-urgent" categories.

To use the term to refer to debugging, vs classification, is even more questionable.

Comment: The word *triage*  doesn't have anything to do with *three*; in French, [it means *to sort, to grade*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trier#French), so the usage for classification of problems is perfectly sound etymologicaly.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the other answer's definition of triage. Copying it here in case the other answer changes:

> Triage is the process of quickly examining sick or injured people, for example after an accident or a battle, so that those who are in the most serious condition can be treated first.

---

However, in a software development environment, I would argue that "triage" refers to troubleshooting/fixing problems **on the production server**, in a live environment.
The live application is the "sick or injured person" from the definition of triage.

If you mean "debugging" as in "debugging on the production server", then it is similar, but you need to make that distinction clear, as it is not clear from only calling it "debugging".
Without any distinction made, I would expect the debugging to be done in a local (safe) testing environment; which excludes the inherent connotation of urgency (critical to patient survival) that triage is most often related to.

*I could elaborate more on specific ways to debug, e.g. the reproduction of issues on the live environment in the testing environment. However, that is a level of distinction that cannot be accurately described by "triage" and I am therefore considering it irrelevant for the current question.*

---

Please do note that these are analogies, and they are not only bound by semantical definition, but also whether or not they are understood in the context that they are used.
As software development is a very abstract field, it's hard to pinpoint accurate analogies. If you look at the definition of the analogy closely enough, you will always find *some* way in which it doesn't really apply to the referenced software development concept.